# Comment vs Reply in a social feed

Tags: social-media, facebook, comments, feed

In a social feed, what is the best term to be used against the posts ? Should it be "Reply" or "Comment"
For example in Facebook, it says "Comment", however in Yammer it says "Reply".

[image: Facebook Feed]

[image: Yammer Feed]

What should be ideal phrase for it? "Comment" or "Reply" ?

Comment: That really depends on the model of your social platform and the nature/context in which it's users interact...

Answer (score 4):

There is no "ideal phrase" for "it".
They are both different terms that mean different things.

**Comment**

> a note explaining, illustrating, or criticizing the meaning of a
> writing Comments on the passage were printed in the margin.
>
> an observation or remark expressing an opinion or attitude critical
> comments constructive comments
>
> a judgment expressed indirectly sees the film as a comment on modern
> values

**Reply**

> say something in response to something someone has said.
>
> a verbal or written answer.

The explanation of the word that fits the use-case of your application better will be the "ideal".

Comment: I would add here that it also depends on what you want to do beyond the surface layer - Facebook also allows "Replies" to "Comments"